# How do activities know what R is?

Tags: android, android-activity

In an android Activity based class, you do not have to import the R class explicitly when accessing your resources. However, in non-activity classes you do.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: It needs to be imported in any class that isn't in the same package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you do...look at your import list. If you're using Eclipse, you may have to expand it to see it. R is a generated class file and has to be imported like any other class you wish to use.

Comment: Thanks - it happens that all my activities are in the same package as R, so an import isn't required. That's what caught me out!